# Rownum in sql INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I want use `rownum` in following query select, i use of it true in following first query but don't know how should use from it in following second query?

First query that work true:

```
$this -> db -> query("
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, 
       t.* 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table 
        ORDER  BY id DESC 
        LIMIT  $offset, $coun) t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
")
```

I echo above rownum in html code on `foreach` as: `echo intval($row -> rownum + $offset)`

Second query(i want use from it in this query, how is for this query?):

```
$this -> db -> query("
SELECT tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       tour_foreign_residence.name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term 
FROM   tour_foreign 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) 
WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
")
```

Comment: Reading & assigning the same variable in a select statement is explicitly undefined behaviour, see the (badly worded) manual on those topics. As of 8.0 one can use window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, simply adding the `@rownum` to the start of the `SELECT` list and the `@rownum` reset as an implicit JOIN onto the end.  I tested this against one of my databases with a similar JOIN and it appears to work correctly.

It looks peculiar to mix explicit `JOIN`s with the implicit join against the `@rownum` reset pseudotable, but I don't know of a way to perform an explicit `JOIN` there when there is no common column.   If anyone can improve that situation, please comment.

```
$this -> db -> query("
SELECT
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
       tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       tour_foreign_residence.name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term 
FROM   tour_foreign 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ),
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
");
```

**UPDATE** an explicit `JOIN` without an `ON` clause also works:

```
FROM   tour_foreign 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
       JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Comment: You could `... CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r` or (in MySQL it works!) a `JOIN` without `ON` clause: `... JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r`

Comment: @ypercube I tried to `LEFT JOIN` w/o an `ON` clause, which was a syntax error. You're right - a straight `JOIN` works.

Comment: One could also have `a CROSS JOIN b ON a.id=b.id`. No distinction between INNER JOINs and CROSS JOINs !

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
$this -> db -> query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, 
       t.* 
FROM   (SELECT tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       tour_foreign_residence.name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term 
FROM   tour_foreign 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) 
WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%") t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
")
```